# In express I have a route that doesn't match and I want to know why?

Tags: express, routes

When I send:

```
PATCH /55148df6935c4bac084b30b2/token/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NTE0OGRmNjkzNWM0YmFjMDg0YjMwYjIiLCJpYXQiOjE0MzAyNTE2OTg5NDIsImV4cCI6MTQzMDI1MTkzODk0Mn0.n8Itqpaf7hjyq23ke977S0oamqXSwEF9iFR62Mlo9Sw
```

I always get back 404? Why? What am I missing?

The route is

```
router.patch('/:id/token/(.+)/', ...)
```

Clearly I am missing some assumption.  Is the string too long? Is the '.' in the string causing issues?  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express doesn't accept raw regex patterns in the path like this. You need to attach them to a named route parameter. You could specify a regex like this: `:token([\\w\.]+)`, but the default `:token` should already match your test string. For example, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
router.patch('/:id/token/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log('My ID:', req.params.id);
    console.log('My token:', req.params.token);
})
```

But I would also suggest sending `PATCH` data in the body of the request and not in the request path. You can send them as url encoded form parameters (eg `token=1234abcd`) or as JSON for example. This is more "canonical" and the other advantage is that you don't have potentially sensitive information getting saved in the browser history and HTTP logs.

Comment: The first thing I tried, before posting this question, was to attempt your suggestion of '/:id/token/:token' since that was the easy thing to do.  But that  failed with 404 -- but why was the puzzle.  But I agree that the better and more canonical thing to do is to shift to send this :token as a parameter.  I will do that and then report back.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Amazingly shifting to '/:id' and sending: PATCH http://example.com/55148df6935c4bac084b30b2?token=eyJ0eXAi…TgsImV4cCI6MTQzNTUwMzQzMTc1OH0.NuRrUBR-hQBlT7sXz36Y_oHAKipDOHupEt2zneKUN-o give s the 404 (Not Found) as before.... Next I will try sending json and hiding this odd token structure.

Comment: As I looked very carefully, I realized that in my code I had a missing s... i.e. the correct path was '/api/users/:id' and I had '/api/user/:id' hence the 404.  So Now all ways as expected.  Thanks for your insight.  -- one of my favorite sayings: 'dumb is really powerful' :-).

Comment: "So, Lone Star, now you see that evil will always triumph because good is dumb."